# htaccess RewriteRule IP Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ip, port

im trying to get this working

```
RewriteRule ^query/([0-9_-]+)$ query.php?ip=$1
```

above rule im wanting to do this...

> query.php?ip=IP:PORT

into this

> query/IP:PORT

but having no luck keep getting a 404 page not found error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably also need a `.` and `:` inside your grouping:

```
RewriteRule ^query/([0-9_-:.]+)$ query.php?ip=$1
```

since IP addresses typically have `.`'s separating the 4 blocks.